# Constant crashes near Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, mods

I've tried everything. I have about 50 mods, none of them alter Whiterun in any way. I've made the SKSE patch with a skse.ini and raised the memory. Decreased actor/item/etc. fade. Nothing helped. Every time I get near the companions who are fighting the giant, I get a CTD. I used LOOT and tes5 edit.

My load order:

```
GameMode=Skyrim

Skyrim.esm
Update.esm
Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp
Dawnguard.esm=1
Unofficial Dawnguard Patch.esp
HearthFires.esm
Unofficial Hearthfire Patch.esp
Dragonborn.esm
Unofficial Dragonborn Patch.esp
ETaC - RESOURCES.esm
RSkyrimChildren.esm
ETaC - Complete.esp
3DNPC.esp
Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp
Hothtrooper44_ArmorCompilation.esp
Hothtrooper44_Armor_Ecksstra.esp
SkyUI.esp
RaceMenu.esp
RaceMenuPlugin.esp
RaceMenuOverlays.esp
Cloaks.esp
SoSFC-LF.esp
UFO - Ultimate Follower Overhaul.esp
SofiaFollower.esp
HoldBorderBanners.esp
VioLens.esp
Dodge Mod.esp
PrinceandPauperRS.esp
RSChildren - Complete.esp
RSChildren_PatchUSKP.esp
SameWalkRunSpeedsLite.esp
FCO - Follower Commentary Overhaul.esp
DineWithFollowers.esp
360WalkandRunPlus-RunBackwardSpeedAdjust.esp
Faction Crossbows.esp
CardGame.esp
SleepTight.esp
1nivWICCloaks.esp
1nivWICSkyCloaksPatch.esp
Sleeved Guards.esp
Immersive detection of NPC.esp
All Geared Up.esp
Action Combat.esp
BlackHorseCourier.esp
Convenient Horses.esp
Alternate Start - Live Another Life.esp
```

Even the slightest help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you turned on Papyrus script logging in your skyrim.ini file? The name of the last script to run before the crash would be a clue to what caused the crash. See [this forum post for examples](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/703954-are-you-having-constant-exterior-ctds-ive-finally-found-your-solution/) of checking the logs.

Comment: Even with nothing altering Whiterun itself, you can have issues with just dialogue or a combat script that is running. Anything that loads something that overrides essential items / scripts will cause a crash. Any mod that overrides another mod's scripts will cause something to not load properly as well. I would start by taking out anything that isn't a standalone item and has nothing to do with altering items.

Comment: 'Sleeved Guards.esp' really nothing? Judging by the name of the mod it is altering Whiterun, or better said, the guards of Whiterun. (I don't know the mod itself). Just disable all mods and enable them one by one to see what causes the issue.

Comment: My papyrus log: http://textuploader.com/ebn7   It's quite weird tho.. It mentions mods that I've never even downloaded, like Wyrmstooth and skyREAL.... Maybe a mod depends on these ones?

Comment: Unplug Violens.esp and try again, perhaps Convenient Horses.esp could also be a problem, though it says the errors can be ignored.

Comment: I'll try that, thx.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I uninstalled both violens and convenient horses correctly (hope so). I followed all uninstall instructions on the mods sites. Still getting the crash. And for some reason, there's still the mcm violens menu although it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Run Skyrim three or four times to get three or four logs, then look at the last couple lines in each file. If the same script is showing up in *each* crash, for example the `ehs_staggerControl.psc` script mentioned in the log you linked to, then the crash has something to do with that script. If it's *not* the same script every time, then it's not a script issue, or it's just a matter of too many scripts running at the same time. Other possible crash causes could include memory problems (for example, increasing uGridsToLoad beyond what your system can handle) or corrupt save files.

`ehs_staggerControl.psc` seems to be from the Every Hit Staggers or Every Hit Staggers Extended mods. It is also linked to another mod called Action Combat. which I see you have installed. If that is the script that shows up in every crash log, then that's the mod responsible.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/85xj Here's my latest crash report.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/85gv Next one.

Comment: Well, the last lines are all differentin these reports, so I assume it's not caused by action combat.

Comment: So, I removed action combat, and suprisingly, this makes me able to get closer to the giant, but I still crash when I get too close to it.